# Resize gameObject when it has extended a restricted area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resize, block, gameobject

So here i have an image will provide a better understanding of my problem.
So currently i have some white blocks and within the white blocks i have some cyan bordered boxes.
So the current problem i want to solve now is.
Whenever the white boxes are extended outside the cyan bordered boxes. I want to resize them so they are inside the cyan bordered boxes.
Such like the one fifth on from the top.

How can i solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**Edit**

```
void Update() {

    if( numOfGeneratedGuideline < numOfGuidelineToGenerate ) {
        Generate_Guideline_Positons(numOfGeneratedGuideline);
        Generate_Platform_Positions_And_Scale(numOfGeneratedGuideline);
        Generate_Platforms(numOfGeneratedGuideline);
        numOfGeneratedGuideline++;
    }

}

void Generate_Guideline_Positons(int i) {

    float tempGuidelineOffset = groundHeight + ( guidelineOffset * ( i + 1 ) );

    guidelinePosX[i] = worldWidth / 2;
    guidelinePosY[i] = tempGuidelineOffset;
    guidelinePosZ[i] = 0;

}

void Generate_Platform_Positions_And_Scale(int i) {

    randomGuidelineNumber = Random.Range(1, numOfGuidelineToGenerate + 1);

    float tempPlatformPosXMin = ( worldWidth - guidelineWidth ) / 2;
    Debug.Log(tempPlatformPosXMin);
    float tempPlatformPosXMax = worldWidth - tempPlatformPosXMin;
    Debug.Log(tempPlatformPosXMax);
    float tempPlatformPosY = groundHeight + ( guidelineOffset * ( i + 1 ) );

    platformPosX[i] = Random.Range(tempPlatformPosXMin, tempPlatformPosXMax);
    platformPosY[i] = tempPlatformPosY;
    platformPosZ[i] = 0;

    platformScaleX[i] = Random.Range(minPlatformScaleRange, maxPlatformScaleRange);
    platformScaleY[i] = 1;
    platformScaleZ[i] = 1;

    //22 29 36 43 50

}

void Generate_Platforms(int i) {

    GameObject newplatform = Instantiate(platformPrefab, new Vector3(platformPosX[i], platformPosY[i], platformPosZ[i]), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    newplatform.transform.localScale = new Vector3(platformScaleX[i], platformScaleY[i], platformScaleZ[i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the specifics of Unity, but in any case, you'll need to do a test on the rectangles.

Let's say `cyan` is the Rectangle of the Cyan gameObject and `gray` is the Rectangle of the Gray gameObject. Just a note: the `left` or `top` properties may be the `x` and `y` properties, while the `right` and `bottom` properties may be `x + width` and `y + height`.

```
if (gray.left < cyan.left) //Out of bounds on the left
    gray.left = cyan.left;
if (gray.right > cyan.right) //Out of bounds on the right / past the right edge
    gray.right = cyan.right;
if (gray.top < cyan.top) //Out of bounds on the top
    gray.top = cyan.top;
if (gray.bottom > cyan.bottom) //Out of bounds on the bottom / gray stretches below cyan
    gray.bottom = cyan.bottom;
```

This is, of course assuming a positive-x and negative-y world. E.g. The bottom is a larger number than the top and the left side is a smaller number than the right side.